# Javascript - Calling a function

Tags: javascript

```
<div id='dependent'>
<input type="button" value="Add" id='btn' onclick='addfunction()' />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var a = 1;
    var b = 1;
    var c = 1;

    function addfunction() {

        var c1 = document.createElement('input');
        c1.type = "checkbox";
        c1.id = "a" + a++;
        var c2 = document.createElement('input');
        c2.type = "checkbox";
        c2.id = "b" + b++;
        var c3 = document.createElement('input');
        c3.type = "checkbox";
        c3.id = "c" + c++;
        var c4 = document.createElement('br');


        document.getElementById("dependent").appendChild(c1);
        document.getElementById("dependent").appendChild(c2);
        document.getElementById("dependent").appendChild(c3);
        document.getElementById("dependent").appendChild(c4);
        // c1.onclick = dep();
        // function dep() { alert(this.id); }
        c1.onclick = function () { alert(this.id); };

    }
</script>
```

When i call the function like this,

```
c1.onclick = function () { alert(this.id); };
```

it works as expected. i.e, when i click on the checkbox, the alert appears with its id.

But if i call the function in this way,

```
c1.onclick = dep();
function dep() { alert(this.id); }
```

The alert appears, when i click on 'Add' button(on calling addfunction()). why?

Comment: Because you are calling it, not assigning its to the event.
While in the previous one you are attaching a function and not calling at this point.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you're *executing `dep()` and assign the return value* to `c1.onclick`.

If you want to assign the function itself, *don't call it*:

```
c1.onclick = dep;
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that `dep()` is a function invocation expression. So what you are actually doing here is calling the function `dep()` and then assigning the result (`undefined`) to `c1.onclick`. You should do the following instead:

```
function dep() { alert(this.id); }
c1.onclick = dep;
```

Comment: Actually he's assigning `undefined` and NOT `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing **result of function invocation** instead **reference to that function** that you would required to be invoked on asynchronous call on click event.

so change this

```
c1.onclick = dep();
```

to

```
c1.onclick = dep;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to assign the result of calling `dep()` (undefined) to onclick. You should assign the function itself

```
 c1.onclick = dep;
```

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
   c1.onclick = dep();
```

Actually calls dep. See the parenthesis???. That's what they do, they actually execute the code. The anonymous function seems to be the way to go. Beware of the **this** word though. On

```
   c1.onclick = function () { alert(this.id); };
```

this can refer to the function itself if you "name" it. Since you already refered to c1, c2, and c3 you can do various solutions like:

```
c1.onclick=function() {alert(c1.id);}
```

or

```
function click_handler(v_param) {alert(v_param.id);}
c1.onclick=function() {click_handler(c1);}
```

Scope in JS can be tricky if you try to look at it as a C or C++ like language.

Hope that helps!.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with scoping

Comment: The problem is that the OP is calling the function and assigning the result instead of assigning it, nothing to do with scope

Comment: Oh, I see. I just wanted to point out the scoping issues when using non-anonymous functions, in case you wanted to try them out. Also, you said shipping, instead of scoping, that's why I didn't get it. I don't know why I got the impression you were the OP...

Comment: And Spanish is not my native language